# Как всегда проверять загрузку изображений из массива и после выполнять функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу реализовать прелоудер на странице, но не после загрузки страницы, а всегда после выполнения функций. Сами функции отслеживать кажется нет смысла, так как они выполняются быстро, а вот картинки которые загружают эти функции грузят страницу. Хочу чтоб когда шла подгрузка картинок из массива появлялся прелоудер, а после загрузки исчезал.
Как это можно реализовать? Страница со скриптом тут - https://euroelectric.kz/konfigurator2

Пробовал делать так

```
var imgs = document.images,
    len = imgs.length,
    counter = 0;

[].forEach.call( imgs, function( img ) {
    if(img.complete)
      incrementCounter();
    else
      img.addEventListener( 'load', incrementCounter, false );
} );

function incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
    if ( counter === len ) {
        console.log( 'All images loaded!' );
    }
}
```

А в массивах писал так

```
...
content_el1.innerHTML = arr
      .filter(([collect, mechtype]) => {
        return (collectValue == collect)
        && (mechTypeValue == "allmax" || mechTypeValue == mechtype)
      })
      .map(([collect, mechtype, href, src, text]) => `
        <a href="${href}" > <div class="varic2">
            <img class="notact2" src="${src}" onload="incrementCounter();"/>
          <div>${text}</div>
        </div></a>
      `).join("");
```

Но работает только при первой загрузке

Comment: Все можно реализовать гораздо проще: `map` массива URL в массив промисов (создающих `Image` с резолвом на событии `loadend` или отдельно `load` c `error`) + `Promise.all`. Если нужно обрабатывать ошибки загрузки, с промисами это тоже не проблема (можно либо общий режект смотреть, либо резолвить булевое значение успешности загрузки и сопоставлять полученный массив с исходным массивом URL).

Comment: Это даже на словах звучит пугающе и сложно)) Вы не могли бы дать простой пример этой реализации?

Comment: Так а что сложного в `const results = urls.map(url => new Promise(....));` и `await Promise.all(results);` в трае? Пример - мог бы написать, будь времечко на это)) Тогда я бы сразу и написал ответ, вместо коммента. Может это получится позже, хз. А пока что, предлагаю попробовать сделать такое самостоятельно, вместо того чтобы не ждать готовенького в бездействии. Тем боле что если в результате этого "попробовать" возникнут трудности - о них можно задать отдельный (уже конкретный) вoпрос, и это тоже будет полезно.

Comment: Кстати, тут все-таки предлагается именно чинить/отлаживать предоставленный код (чего сообщество на данный момент не желает делать), но не заменять его более оптимальными решениями - если хочется второго, то стоит переформулировать вoпрос и добавить [repro] с версткой и массивом (в качестве условий задачи). Ну а если реплика "звучит пугающе и сложно" это только несогласие с предложением - ок, не настаиваю.